# Is "every bit" an adverb?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I found out 'every bit' is similar expression to 'entirely'
while reading through another post put up on here.

So in this line (from the movie 'Dead poets society' [Source:Yarn Clips](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/a81a3d80-6004-4fc2-9b6a-829a1814ab6d)):

> "It's **every bit** as tough as they say unless you're genius like Meeks."

Does "every bit" function as an adverb which modifies '**It's as tough as ~**"?

Answer (score 1):

> *It* = **Subject** AND *'s every bit as tough as they say* = **Predicate** consisting of:
>
> - *'s* = **Verb**
> - *every bit as tough as they say* = **Predicative Complement**

***Every bit*** is an idiom which means

> quite; just; equally (used in comparisons with ***as***)
>
> - ***every bit as*** *funny* ***as*** the other show ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/every-bit))

In your sentence, ***every bit*** is a **Noun Phrase**, being part of the Predicative Complement ("*every bit as tough as they say*"). The NP ***every bit*** is functioning as a modifier of the adjective "tough", answering to the question "how tough?". Within this NP, ***every*** is an adjective which functions as a determinative of the noun ***bit***.

As the phrase does not contain any adverb, it cannot be an adverb phrase, although:

1. it carries a meaning which could be expressed by an adverb

and

2. it modifies an adjective in the way an adverb could modify it.

It can, however, be replaced by an adverb:

> It's ***equally/comparably*** as tough as they say unless you're genius like Meeks.

Note that ***every bit*** is informal. ([Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/every+bit))

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. 
You have there a very complex adjectival phrase. An adverb and a verb can become a compound adjec, but it does not here.

Comment: Then what would 'every bit' in this sentence function as? Could you give me more explanations?